# I´m having an issue with FullCalendar control of http://fullcalendar.io/ when having multiples "all day events"

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Seems that on several entries, provides me with a link to show the remain items "+## more".
Currently when clicking on link to expand and view all items, its returning an empty dialogue.

The versión fullCalendar is: 2.1.1

The problem is with these propertys:   allDayDefault: true, or in event allDay:true,  when clicking on link to expand and view all items.

Im started the calendar with:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

   $('#calendar').fullCalendar
   ({

                 header: {
                      left: 'prev,next today',
                      center: 'title',
                      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                  },
                  eventLimit: true, 
                  selectable: true,
                  selectHelper: true,
                  allDayDefault: true,


                  eventSources: [getCalData()],
    });

    function getCalData() {

              var urlAux = baseUrl + '/pagweb/WSAgenda.asmx/test';

              var source = [{}];
              $.ajax({
                  async: false,
                  type: "POST",
                  contentType: "application/json",
                  data: "{}",
                  url: urlAux,
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (data) {

                      if (data.d != null) {

                          for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {


                              source.push({
                                  id: data.d[i].id,
                                  start: new Date(data.d[i].start),
                                  end: new Date(data.d[i].end),
                                  title: data.d[i].title,
                                  className: data.d[i].color,


                              });

                          };

                      }
                      else {
                          return null;
                      }

                  }

              });
              return source;
          }

      });

  </script>
```

getCalData is a json request.

Comment: You probably need to actually render the calendar within the callback of your AJAX request. Right now you have a race condition where the render call is "using" the data before the data is actually returned. (And it should be noted that no data will be returned there.)

Comment: for that reason im use  async: false in ajax request, and only happend the problem with this property  allDayDefault: true, if I dont put this property the link "+## more" works correctly.

Comment: Not a mistake, but.... using a synchronous blocking call is 'always' a bad idea :)

Comment: yes i know i try with async: true and render the calendar again, but the issue persists, do I decided put in async:false for make sure that i have all the data before render the callendar.